# Twitter feed adding whitespace to page

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter

My (WordPress) page has two divs, 'main' and 'sidebar'. I have a JavaScript that runs on page load to add padding to whichever div is shorter, making the two equal in length so that the background gradients line up properly, e.g.: http://fightprimetc.com/gabriel/

However, on any page where I have a Twitter feed displayed in the sidebar, the padding is not evened up properly. Instead, a white box porportional in height to the Twitter feed shows up under the 'main' div, e.g.: http://fightprimetc.com/lawenforcement/

I made the Twitter feed shorter, and the white box shrunk accordingly; if I remove the Twitter feed entirely, the box goes away entirely.

My only guess is that the Twitter feed is being inserted into the sidebar after my padding-evening JavaScript runs, but since the JS goes on page load, that really shouldn't be the case--right?

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
<body onload="evenupmainandsidebar()">

function evenupmainandsidebar() {
    var mainheight = document.getElementById('main').offsetHeight;
    var sideheight = document.getElementById('sidebar').offsetHeight;

    if (sideheight > mainheight) {
        var pixelated = (sideheight - mainheight) + "px";
        document.getElementById('main').style.paddingBottom = pixelated;
    }

    else if (mainheight > sideheight) {
        var pixelated =  (mainheight - sideheight) + "px";
        document.getElementById('sidebar').style.paddingBottom = pixelated;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I verified that the Twitter feed was, indeed, loading after evenupmainandsidebar() ran. My solution was to fix the height and line-height of the anchor tag containing the Twitter feed at 427px; so for the millisecond or two before the tweets load, there's a big blank 427px box in the sidebar, but that box allows evenupmainandsidebar() to set the padding correctly. And once the tweets load, they just fill the box.

If I have time, I will do what jorblume said and fix this issue properly.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly this is a CSS issue, not really a javascript issue.  You shouldn't be touching the DOM if it can be fixed on page load, always try to fix style issues using stylesheets first.

The quick fix is to add a height on #torso so that it will always encompass the content and prevent the social media feeds from ever messing with the main content.

## torso { height: 1170px; }

The real, in depth solution is to refactor your css so everything properly sizes when new content is added.

Comment: Thanks; I will definitely refactor the CSS if I have time. For the time being, setting a large torso height only caused a second background gradient to appear under the big white box. I hacked a quick fix by setting the height and line-height of the twitter feed anchor at 427px, so before the actual tweets load, at least there's a 427px blank box in the sidebar that evenupmainandsidebar() can use to make correct calculations.